# EJabberd Simple Examples

Tags: ejabberd

I have just install EJabberd 14.07 in mac os. I am new in EJabberd, I want to learn  basic like How to create Hello World Example, What will be the structure of Project, How compile and run EJabberd Program? I have searched but didn't find any useful link who help me understand basic things, If you know then suggest some link which help me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJabberd is a jabber (XMPP [instant messaging]) daemon, you don't make hello world's with it ; you communicate through it ...

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, So Do you know any basic example using erlang, Which help me to understand EJabberd?

Comment: You can go to http://www.erlang.org/doc.html where you can find examples and course

Comment: This is about erlang, I am looking for ejabberd example. I have found https://www.process-one.net/en/wiki/ejabberd_HTTP_request_handlers/ but I am confuse about where to create .erl file and how to run this Program?

Comment: Finally I got the link http://www.process-one.net/en/wiki/, this is for ejabberd documentation. If you are looking for basic example with instruction how to run then follow http://metajack.im/2008/08/28/writing-ejabberd-modules-presence-storms/   Enjoy!!!!